# How to combine multiple arrays with same amount of items in php

Tags: php, arrays, web, merge

Is there a way to combine multiple arrays with same amount of items? See below the 4 arrays with 5 items inside:

```
$type = array('Type 1','Type 2','Type 3',' Type 4','Type 5');
$desc = array('Description 1','Description 2','Description 3','Description 4','Description 5');
$brand = array('Brand 1','Brand 2','Brand 3','Brand 4','Brand 5');
$model = array('Model 1','Model 2','Model 3','Model 4','Model 5');
```

Expected Results:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Type 1
        [1] => Description 1
        [2] => Brand 1
        [3] => Model 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Type 2
        [1] => Description 2
        [2] => Brand 2
        [3] => Model 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Type 3
        [1] => Description 3
        [2] => Brand 3
        [3] => Model 3
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => Type 4
        [1] => Description 4
        [2] => Brand 4
        [3] => Model 4
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => Type 5
        [1] => Description 5
        [2] => Brand 5
        [3] => Model 5
    )
```

I'm not PHP expert please help me :)

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried--searches or code attempts--to answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
$type = array('Type 1','Type 2','Type 3',' Type 4','Type 5');
$desc = array('Description 1','Description 2','Description 3','Description 4','Description 5');
$brand = array('Brand 1','Brand 2','Brand 3','Brand 4','Brand 5');
$model = array('Model 1','Model 2','Model 3','Model 4','Model 5');

$result = array();
foreach($type as $key=>$val){ // Loop though one array
    $val2 = $desc[$key]; 
    $val3 = $brand[$key];
    $val4 = $model[$key]; 
    $result[$key] =array($val,$val2, $val3,$val4);
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Thank you for helping, but the result is Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 0
)

Comment: Hi @SNTiwari, it works. Then all I need to do is to add key to array item.     
        $result[$key]['type'] = $val;
        $result[$key]['description'] = $val2;
        $result[$key]['brand'] = $val3;
        $result[$key]['model'] = $val4;

Thanks so much for you help :).

Answer (score 0):

Simple loop through any array, Use that array's key to get ither array data and create new array

```
$type = array('Type 1','Type 2','Type 3',' Type 4','Type 5');
$desc = array('Description 1','Description 2','Description 3','Description 4','Description 5');
$brand = array('Brand 1','Brand 2','Brand 3','Brand 4','Brand 5');
$model = array('Model 1','Model 2','Model 3','Model 4','Model 5');

foreach($type as $key=>$type_val){ // Loop though one array
    $desc_val = $desc[$key] ?? ""; 
    $brand_val = $brand[$key] ?? "";
    $model_val = $model[$key] ?? ""; 
    $result[$key] = array($type_val,$desc_val,$brand_val,$model_val); // combine 
}

print_r($result);
```

**Note :** `??` will only work for php 7 + for older version change `$desc[$key] ?? ""` to `isset($desc[$key]) ? $desc[$key] : ""`

[DEMO](https://eval.in/902641)

Answer (score 0):

This is perfect and tested code:

```
<?php
$type = array('Type 1','Type 2','Type 3',' Type 4','Type 5');
$desc = array('Description 1','Description 2','Description 3','Description 4','Description 5');
$brand = array('Brand 1','Brand 2','Brand 3','Brand 4','Brand 5');
$model = array('Model 1','Model 2','Model 3','Model 4','Model 5');

$result = array();

foreach ($type as $id => $key) {
    $result[$id] = array($key,$desc[$id],$brand[$id],$model[$id]);
}
echo "<pre>";print_r($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

[array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) is really all you need here.

```
$type = array('Type 1','Type 2','Type 3',' Type 4','Type 5');
$desc = array('Description 1','Description 2','Description 3','Description 4','Description 5');
$brand = array('Brand 1','Brand 2','Brand 3','Brand 4','Brand 5');
$model = array('Model 1','Model 2','Model 3','Model 4','Model 5');

$res = array_map(function(...$val) {return $val;}, $type, $desc, $brand, $model);
print_r($res);
```

[See it in Action](https://3v4l.org/vEQ5T)